# Stacking time series in Google Sheet Combo chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I can approximate a stacked time-series plot using the *Combo chart* option in Google Sheets:

[image]

But it's not quite a "real" time series plot because the temporal gaps are not represented. Compare to this *Scatter chart* based on the same dataset:

[image]

Can I have the best of both worlds: a stacked scatter plot that uses X-axis values as timestamps, not labels?

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround than answer.. but manually inserting empty rows (with dates) will pad the X-axis such that gaps are rendered:

[image: Sheet with empty data rows added]

[image: Combo plot with gaps]

Of course this requires modifying the data set, and also the dates are still treated as labels.